# Finding the intersection of 2 arbitrary cubes in 3d

Tags: java, 3d, geometry, intersection

So, I'd like to figure out a function that allows you to determine if two cubes of arbitrary rotation and size intersect.

If the cubes are not arbitrary in their rotation (but locked to a particular axis) the intersection is simple; you check if they intersect in all three dimensions by checking their bounds to see if they cross or are within one another in all three dimensions. If they cross or are within in only two, they do not intersect. This method can be used to determine if the arbitrary cubes are even candidates for intersection, using their highest/lowest x, y, and z to create an outer bounds.

That's the first step. In theory, from that information we can tell which 'side' they are on from each other, which means we can eliminate some of the quads (sides) from our intersection. However, I can't assume that we have that information, since the rotation of the cubes may make it difficult to determine simply.

My thought is to take each pair of quads, find the intersection of their planes, then determine if that line intersects with at least one edge of each of the pairs of sides. If any pair of sides has a line of intersection that intersects with any of their edges, the quads intersect. If none intersect, the two cubes do not intersect.

We can then determine the depth of the intersection on the second cube by where the plane-intersection line intersects with its edge(s).

This is simply speculative, however. Is there a better, more efficient way to determine the intersection of these two cubes? I can think of a number of different ways to do this, and I can also tell that they could be very different in terms of amount of computation required.

I'm working in Java at the moment, but C/C++ solutions are cool too (I can port them); even psuedocode since it is perhaps a big question.

Comment: Doesn't [Separating Axis Theorm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem) work in 3D as in 2D?

Comment: I think it might. I hadn't thought of that; I already use a version of '3D as three sets of 2D'. This might be simpler than I thought!

Comment: I bet that works for you. Im pretty sure i read it did when I was researching 2d polygon intersection

Comment: Seems like you'd apply the SAT for each face's normal against the other cube. If any of the tests fails, the cubes do not intersect. For some shapes, I'll have to double-up because the quads are 'bent' (i.e, the triangles are not flush.) It looks like a max of 16 tests for any regular cube / rectangular prism pair.

Comment: That sounds correct. Is this a problem? If so you could look into spatial partitioning to reduce the pairs which need checking. Also I don't know your intent, but of the cubes are rotating quickly or the time step in animation is great be aware you can miss intersections without a more advanced solution.

Comment: Yes, frame skip could (for instance) cause you to miss the point where the cube's corner crosses inside the other one. For that general problem, I actually used a combined AABB as a sniff test when things were moving at high speed relative to the size of intersecting objects. In this case, I could create a hypercube from both cubes do SAT on the faces that are 'in between'. With rotations it's iffier, though I saw a link where voroni spaces were used with circles.

Comment: Are you looking for someone to post code that performs cube vs cube intersection given some starting state and a rotation then?

Comment: All that has been posted so far is theory; even if I use SAT to solve this, if someone else looks for the same question, they will be sorely disappointed to find nothing to work with other than some links to general explanations of a mathematical theory.

Answer (score 3):

To find the intersection (contact) points of two arbitrary cubes in three dimensions, you have to do it in two phases:

1. Detect collisions. This is usually two phases itself, but for simplicity, let's just call it "collision detection".

The algorithm will be either SAT (Separating axis theorem), or some variant of polytope expansion/reduction. Again, for simplicity, let's assume you will be using SAT.

I won't explain in detail, as others have already done so many times, and better than I could. The "take-home" from this, is that collision detection is not designed to tell you *where* a collision has taken place; only that it has taken place.

2. Upon detection of an intersection, you need to compute the contact points. This is done via a polygon clipping algorithm. In this case, let's use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm

There are easier, and better ways to do this, but SAT is easy to grasp in 3d, and SH clipping is also easy to get your head around, so is a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the field of computer graphics. They have many means. E.g. [Weiler–Atherton clipping algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler%E2%80%93Atherton_clipping_algorithm). There are also many datastructures that could ease up the process for you. To mention AABBs ([Axis-aligned bounding boxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume)).

Comment: Yes, I use (and describe) AABB's in my question.

Comment: Yes, kind of. With AABBs you can verify that arbitrary shapes do *not* intersect, if the corresponding AABBs do *not* intersect. If they do, you have to do further testing. Read up on computer graphics, I'm sure you'll find a proper solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the separating axis theorem. it should apply in 3d as it does in 2d.

Comment: Clearly, you'd need to apply the SAT to each face of each cube against the eight points of the other cube.  I see a lot of geometric examples, but nothing in terms of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you create polygons from the sides of the cubes then another approach is to use Constructive Space Geometry (CSG) operations on them. By building a Binary Space Partitioning (BSP) tree of each cube you can perform an intersection on them. The result of the intersection is a set of polygons representing the intersection. In your case if the number of polygons is zero then the cubes don't intersect.

I would add that this approach is probably not a good real time solution, but you didn't indicate if this needed to happen in frame refresh time or not.

Since porting is an option you can look at the Javascript library that does CSG located at

http://evanw.github.io/csg.js/docs/

I've ported this library to C# at

https://github.com/johnmott59/CGSinCSharp