# (Numerically) calculate intersecting volume of two cuboids

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, intersection, numerical-methods

I have given two cuboids with only one of their axes being aligned (the other two not necessarliy) and the coordinates of their vertices (in a global coordinate system) and I know they are intersecting. I am looking for an algorithm that can calculate the volume of the intersection.

To check for intersection I used the Separating Axis Theorem.

Comment: do you googled it ?

Comment: yes, but I didn't find anything so far.

Comment: @AdrianPfeifle how about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558077/finding-the-intersection-of-2-arbitrary-cubes-in-3d)... ?

Comment: @Paul I don't see where this answers my question? Do you mean the link to the Weiler–Atherton clipping algorithm?

Comment: Do you mean rectangular cuboid or general cuboid?

Comment: @Ante I mean rectangular cuboids

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of two arbitrary rectangles can be constructed by the Sutherland-Hodgman procedure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm). In a nutshell, you clip one of the rectangles four times with the half planes that delimit the other. The result will range from a quadrilateral to an octagon.

[image]

The area of a polygon is found with the shoelace formula.

The intersection voume is a prism of which you know the base and the height.

---

Note that you can generalize the procedure to 3D and implement the intersection of a convex polyhedron with a half-space (clip every face with the half-space and connect the newly formed edges to get the face of the section). This allows you to solve the problem for arbitrarily oriented cuboids.

Answer (score 0):

Since one of axes is aligned, algorithm can be like:

- project cuboids in 2D in aligned axis direction,
- calculate intersection area between two rectangles in 2D,
- project cuboids in 1D on aligned axis,
- calculate intersection of 1D segments,
- resulting volume is area multiplied by segment intersection length.

Comment: Thanks this helps a bit, but basically same problem as before. How do I get the intersection area of two randomly oriented rectangles in 2D?

Comment: In your case they do not have to be randomly oriented. With good projection (transformation) it is possible to position one rectangle in origin with sides axis aligned. Than corners and edges of second rectangle can be checked for intersection with first rectangle, and intrsection polygon can be found.

Comment: and how do I get the intersection polygon? I see many different cases that all need to be covered. Do I need to do a case differentiation for all of those (second rectangle intersecting with one, two, three vertices, intersecting one, two, three edges etc)?

Comment: Intersect all edges of second polygon with first one. That is simple to do. If there are no intersections, result is empty set or inner polygon. With intersections, start with one intersection point, traverse inner polygon until next intersection, than traverse inner (second) polygon until next intersection, and so on until you reach starting point.